accountUnsubscribe and accountSubscribe error: Tried to call a JSON-RPC method when socket was not `CONNECTING` or `OPEN` (`readyState` was 2)
@solana/web3.js in "connection" class internally controls websockets status, but it doesn't show websocket status externally. So, it is not possible check for example "connection.status" before trying to "subscribe" or "unsubscribe" with JSON-RPC methods.
I have this error when trying to subscribe/unsubscribe and websocket is not in rigth state:
accountUnsubscribe error: Tried to call a JSON-RPC method `accountUnsubscribe` but the socket was not `CONNECTING` or `OPEN` (`readyState` was 2) 

And this is not due to websocket version as described in this question, I have the right version.
I connect doing something like this:
const id5 = connection.onAccountChange(
    AccoundAddress,
    (accountInfo, context) =>{ 
        console.log('connected');
    },
    "confirmed"
);

And I try to disconnect doing something like this:
connection.removeAccountChangeListener(id5);

Usually it works fine, but after few hours when I call to unsubscribe and websocket is not connected, it fails as shown before.
I have tried to solve it like this but it doesn't work, it doesn't hadle the error and the program crash with the same error described before:
const removeListener = async (id:number) =>{

    let ok:boolean = false;
    let n_times:number = 1;

    do{

        try{
            await connection.removeAccountChangeListener(id);
            ok = true;
        }catch(error){
            ok = false;
        }            

        if (!ok){
            await delay(1000); // custom function to delay 1s
            console.log(`Try: ${n_times}, Nop: ${id}`);
            n_times++;
        }else{
            console.log(`Try: ${n_times}, Disconnected: ${id}`);
        }

    }while(!ok);

}

I have tried also with this:
const removeListener = async (id:number) =>{

    let ok:boolean = false;
    let n_times:number = 1;

    do{
        ok = true;
        await connection.removeAccountChangeListener(id).catch(error){
            ok = false;
        }            

        if (!ok){
            await delay(1000); // custom function to delay 1s
            console.log(`Try: ${n_times}, Nop: ${id}`);
            n_times++;
        }else{
            console.log(`Try: ${n_times}, Disconnected: ${id}`);
        }

    }while(!ok);

}

Does anybody know:

The proper way to handle this.
If there is any way to know websocket status before doing requests.

It seems that it is not possible to detect this error. I have posted this ohter question.
